# "env: ‘/bin/flask’: No such file or directory" when running "npm run start-backend"

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, windows, flask

Im trying to find the most basic website template with Flask and React,
Im using this repository and following installation instructions

https://github.com/Faruqt/React-Flask

Im using git Bash in Windows 10, and when running `npm run start-backend` it gives me the error:

```
> flask_react@0.1.0 start-backend
> cd backend && env/bin/flask run --no-debugger

env: ‘/bin/flask’: No such file or directory
```

I can't seem to find a solution online

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the default installation in `package.json` was pointing to flask.exe getting installed in the bin folder, which doesn't exist in the repository. Solution is to modify the `"start-backend": "cd backend && ...../venv/Scripts/flask.exe run --no-debugger",`  line